# Apple MDM Vendor genenrated plist file is invalidate when upload to apple push certificate port

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I create the plist file step by http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning, but when i post this plist file to apple push certificate port, it failed and reported as invalide servicetype, service type invalidate null, can anyone help me? Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the vendor's certificate and private key? You should upload the plist_encoded file but not the plist.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing exactly the same error a few days ago, it's surprisingly true that "ServiceType null" is the only logging statement for this problem, good job Apple...

So you need to check a few things to get it working:

1. make sure the account you are using is an enterprise one WITH the mdm option checked when first purchased.
2. when choosing the type of certificate when creating mdm certificate, make sure you use the MDM CSR one under Production, not "Apple Push Notification service SSL (sandbox)" under Development or any other one.
3. also as Kun said, use the encoded_plist, but if you do use the plist.xml, I think you will get another type of error saying "Invalid signing request"

Hope this helps, good luck.